# How to get Feature Importance of XGBoost in scala, using spark?

Tags: scala, xgboost

I am trying to get feature importance of a XGBoost model in Scala 2.11, using Spark 2.1.1. My code so far follows

```
(...)

def get_param(): mutable.HashMap[String, Any] = {

    val params = new mutable.HashMap[String, Any]()
    params += "eta"             -> Configuration.eta
    params += "max_depth"       -> Configuration.maxDepth
    params += "gamma"           -> Configuration.gamma
    params += "objective"       -> Configuration.objective
    params += "alpha"           -> Configuration.alpha
    params += "lambda"          -> Configuration.lambda
    params += "subSample"       -> Configuration.subSample
    params += "minChildWeight"  -> Configuration.minChildWeight

    return params
  }

val model = XGBoost.trainWithDataFrame(trainingDataCached, 
                                       get_param().toMap, 
                                       Configuration.numberOfRounds, 
                                       nWorkers = Configuration.numberOfWorkers, 
                                       useExternalMemory = useExternalMemory )
```

which steps am I missing now?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear. Once the model has been trained, I would like to get the contribution / importance / score of each feature in the model. This normally translates to call the typical method in scikit-learn feature_importance(). However, I don't know how to obtain such information. @BobDalgleish

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
val featureScoreMap = xgbModel.booster.getFeatureScore()
val sortedScoreMap = featureScoreMap.toSeq.sortBy(-_._2) // descending order
```

The getFeatureScore method will return the feature importance map(of type: Map[String, Integer]) where the key is feature index(eg:f0, f1, f2...)(the feature index is same as the feature order in training dataset which you used to train your model) and the integer is feature score(calculated by accumulating information gain of this feature in trained model).

If what you really want is feature real name paired with feature importance score, then you should provide a feature name to feature index map.

Comment: Add some explanation to your code as to why it might work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above says that `xgbModel.booster.getFeatureScore()` computes feature scores by accumulating information gain. This is NOT correct. It actually computes scores by accumulating the number of tree splits for each particular feature.

In XGBoost Version 0.8, the way to get feature importance computed by information gain in Spark is as follows:

```
// first empty string argument means using a null feature map.
val featureScoreMap_gain = xgbModel.nativeBooster.getScore("", "gain")
println("feature importance by information gain is :")
println(featureScoreMap_gain)
```

Comment: Quick comment, this method was added in version 0.9 I believe (it is definitely not available on 0.8)

Comment: how to print the name of the variables instead of f1,f2,...?